# Parsing list of dictionaries in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

This is a dataframe sample (in reality it has more columns, :

|  | _id | answers | extraColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | [{'title': 'dog', 'value': 'True'}, {'title': 'cat', 'value': 'False'}, {'title': 'bird', 'value': 'False'}] | something |
| 1 | b | [{'title': 'food', 'value': 'False'}, {'title': 'water', 'value': 'True'}, {'title': 'wine', 'value': 'False'}] | nothing |
| 2 | c | [] | [] |
| 3 | d | [] | 22 |

I want to add an extra column that represents the total string length of the keys. So for the first row it would be 10 ("dog"+"cat"+"bird"),  then 13, then 0, then 0.

I tried `parsed = df.groupby('_id').answers.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(df.values[0])).reset_index()` but it completely messed up my dataset and parsed my extra column instead, somehow. I was thinking of just creating an extra dataframe out of these dictionaries, and calculating the string length as simple as `df['Length']=df['title'].str.len()`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.join(df['answers'].explode().apply(pd.Series)['title'])
df['extraColumn'] = df.groupby('_id')['title'].transform(lambda x: len(x.str.cat(sep='')))
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['_id'], inplace=True)
```